# Trying to integrate DocuSign into Drupal website

Tags: drupal, docusignapi

My organization is trying to achieve the following workflow using Drupal website with FillPDF and DocuSign:

1. We have a PDF document with text fields.
2. FillPDF fills out the document fields with the specific data from Webform Submission per entity.
3. We would like then to allow a user to sign this document by clicking on "Sign" button.
4. We have also uploaded the same document to DocuSign as a template and added a signature field.
5. So, when user clicks on "Sign" button, we would like them to be redirected to DocuSign eSignature page where they can sign the document.
   5.1. If I understand correctly, at this stage our application must make an API call to the DocuSign eSignature API and request the creation of the Envelope and transmit the document in base64 encoded format, right?
6. When the document is signed, the user should be redirected back to the website and the signed document stored locally on the server.
   6.1. Again, if I understand correctly, at this stage the DocuSign eSignature API should return the signed document to our application, right?

I've been trying to implement this, but cannot really find the correct documentation for this. Is there an existing module available (apart from docusign-signature, which only provides basic exmaples) ?

How would I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

> So, when user clicks on "Sign" button, we would like them to be redirected to DocuSign eSignature page where they can sign the document.

1. Use the DocuSign Oauth JWT grant to obtain an access token for a "service user." A service user is a DocuSign "user" such as order-processing@yourcompany.com. The envelope will then be "sent" by that DocuSign identity. Or you can use the identity of any user on your DocuSign system. (If you can't figure out how to use the DocuSign JWT grant, ask a **new** question on StackOverflow)
2. Create the envelope. Yes you upload the doc as Base64 encoded. Using a DocuSign template is the right way to go. Here's a [live example](https://codepen.io/docusign/pen/MWXPKJY?editors=0010) that uses a template with the composite templates flow. The example doesn't substitute a document. You would substitute your document for the template's document by using the composite template pattern as shown here:

```
Here's the composite template part of the API call for your use case:
Note: 
1. Add the clientUserId since you want that recipient to be
an embedded recipient

compositeTemplates: [
  {
    "document": {
      "documentBase64": "base64 version of the document",
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "anchorfields v2.docx"
    },
    "serverTemplates": [
      {
        "templateId": "71a66510-ad60-49c8-b830-6db8xxxxxxc91",
        "sequence": "1"
      }
    ],
    "inlineTemplates": [
      {
        "sequence": "2",
        "recipients": {
          "signers": [
            {
              "roleName": "signer1",
              "email": "",
              "name": "",
              "recipientId": "1"
              "clientUserId": "xxx"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

3. Use the embedded recipient view to obtain a URL for the signing ceremony.  See the code pen example for how to do this.
4. Redirect the user's browser to the signing ceremony
5. Upon completion of the signature, DocuSign will redirect back to your app.
6. Download the signed doc from DocuSign. Use a webhook notification if needed.
7. Got more questions? Try the above and then **ask a new question on StackOverflow.**